# Cordova file plugin - File not created

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, html5-filesystem

I'm doing an application with Cordova and in order to create and write into a file on my phone I use the plugin file system.
But I've got a problem,: my application launches the function to create but it's impossible to find the file on my phone .. So I suppose that it is not created.

```
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
                alert('deviceready'); 
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fsReceived, errorHandler);
            }, false);

        function fsReceived(fs) {
        alert('fsReceived');
        fs.root.getFile("accounts.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
            alert('Successful');
        }, errorHandler);
    };
```

The alert Successful is printed on my device but no file is created. And I have no errors.

Any issues ?

Comment: are you getting alert('fsReceived');??alert('Successful');??

Comment: Yes. That's why I don't understand. I searched the file at the root of my device but no one.

Comment: ceck out step 4A https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cordova/cordova_file_system.htm....according to this do u have superuser permission?

Comment: Ok, it works ! I searched about superuser permission so I added `<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
  <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="sdcard,cache" />` into my config.xml. Thanks!

Comment: oh that's so nice of me :-) i learned a new thing because of you